# Python Socket Server and parallel timed Tasks

Tags: python, sockets, timer, raspberry-pi, tornado

I'm quite new to python and just hanging at the following problem.

I'm trying to build a plant-watering-automation. As a base a use a tornado socket server which listen to client polls and deliveres the data for visualisation.

For the watering automation I created a ContinuousCallback (every 30 minutes) in which I want to check for humidity and control the pumps (GPIO out).

**The task:** if the Callback starts and it measures to low humidity, it should start to pump by switching the GPIO pins for a defined amount of time. (the time is defined in a SQLITE DB)

**The problem:** how can I do it, that I enter the Callback and start the pump action (I have 4 pumps) and make it end after the defined time? (Timer?, Timer Interrupt?) without influencing the Socket Server IOloop?

.

.

Thank you and best wishes

Sebastian

Comment: sure Timer should work i would think ...

Comment: do you have a code snippet which could help me?
How can I archive 4 different runtimes (GPIO.HIGH) with timers?

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
def on_button_or_whatever():
    setGPIO_HIGH()
    timer = threading.Timer(target=setGPIO_LOW,5.0)
    timer.start()
```

Comment: Thank you. I made it running :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joran I made it.

Here is my code.

```
GPIO_PUMP_1 = 17
GPIO_PUMP_2 = 27
GPIO_PUMP_3 = 22
GPIO_PUMP_4 = 10

#function which switches the relais off (low-active)
def setGPIO_HIGH(pin):
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(pin,     GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin,    GPIO.LOW)
    return True


#function which switches the relais on (low-active)
def setGPIO_LOW(pin):
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(pin,     GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(pin,    GPIO.HIGH)
    return True



#main function for controlling the watering logic
def doStuff():
    setGPIO_HIGH(GPIO_PUMP_1)
    setGPIO_HIGH(GPIO_PUMP_2)
    setGPIO_HIGH(GPIO_PUMP_3)
    setGPIO_HIGH(GPIO_PUMP_4)

    timer1 = threading.Timer(5.0, setGPIO_LOW, [GPIO_PUMP_1])
    timer1.start()
    timer2 = threading.Timer(6.0, setGPIO_LOW, [GPIO_PUMP_2])
    timer2.start()
    timer3 = threading.Timer(7.0, setGPIO_LOW, [GPIO_PUMP_3])
    timer3.start()
    timer4 = threading.Timer(8.0, setGPIO_LOW, [GPIO_PUMP_4])
    timer4.start()

    WebSocketHandler.broadcast("all done")
    return True
```